# How to parse an xml data which is stored in a variable?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

```
  <myroot>  <data txt="some0" txt1 = "some1" txt2 = "some2" >
                 <data2>
                        < bank = "SBI" bank2 = "SBI2" >
                 <data2>
                 <data3>
                        <branch = "bang1" branch = "bang2" >
                 <data3>
            </data>

            <data txt="some0" txt1 = "some1" txt2 = "some2" >
                 <data2>
                        < bank = "citi" bank2 = "citi2" >
                 <data2>
                 <data3>
                        <branch = "bang3" branch = "bang4" >
                 <data3>
            </data> </myroot>
```

This above data is stored in a variable not in an xml file. I am unable to parse it because it is not an xml file. please help me to convert the data to an xml format/file and parse the same, below the script which i am trying:

```
stdout = "<myroot>%s</myroot>" % stdout
print'main data', stdout
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(stdout)
tree1 = ET.parse('tree')
```

In first line of the script i am adding a root tag to data and in main data the xml data which i shown above will be stored, then i am trying to parse it but its throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an error because your XML is wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1301, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1643, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1507, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 25
```

So look at line3, column 25. tada

```
>>> stdout.split('\n')[2][25:]
' bank = "SBI" bank2 = "SBI2" >'
```

Comment: :this is the error  Exception : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tree'
Traceback : 
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: @user2558589, do you have a file or directory called 'tree'?

Comment: nope,i am storing the optput of  ElementTree.fromstring(stdout) in a variable called tree, then trying to parse it.

Comment: @user2558589, You are asking `ET.parse()` to open a file called `'tree'`. That's exactly what the error message is complaining about.

Comment: ya i got it, can u help me to parse the data which is stored in varialbe called stdout ?

Answer (score 0):

It parses fine with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> s = """<myroot>  <data txt="some0" txt1 = "some1" txt2 = "some2" >
...                  <data2>
...                         < bank = "SBI" bank2 = "SBI2" >
...                  <data2>
...                  <data3>
...                         <branch = "bang1" branch = "bang2" >
...                  <data3>
...             </data>
... 
...             <data txt="some0" txt1 = "some1" txt2 = "some2" >
...                  <data2>
...                         < bank = "citi" bank2 = "citi2" >
...                  <data2>
...                  <data3>
...                         <branch = "bang3" branch = "bang4" >
...                  <data3>
...             </data> </myroot>"""

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> print soup.prettify()
<myroot>
 <data txt="some0" txt1="some1" txt2="some2">
  <data2>
   &lt; bank = "SBI" bank2 = "SBI2" &gt;
   <data2>
    <data3>
     <branch "bang1" = branch="bang2">
      <data3>
      </data3>
     </branch>
    </data3>
   </data2>
  </data2>
 </data>
 <data txt="some0" txt1="some1" txt2="some2">
  <data2>
   &lt; bank = "citi" bank2 = "citi2" &gt;
   <data2>
    <data3>
     <branch "bang3" = branch="bang4">
      <data3>
      </data3>
     </branch>
    </data3>
   </data2>
  </data2>
 </data>
</myroot>
```